# Should I protect my cookies from injections?

Tags: php, html

I have this script in my header:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {$_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];}
if (isset($_COOKIE['is_logged_in'])) {$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = $_COOKIE['is_logged_in'];}
```

Should I protect my cookies from injections?
like stripslashes etc.

Comment: How does `stripslashes` "protect from injections"?

Comment: Do your cookies really need protection? Against whom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost you should rethink your authentication system. Because currently, anyone who knows how to alter cookies can impersonate any user without [proper authentication](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication). That’s a way more actual security flaw.

Injection vulnerabilities depend on the actual context the values are inserted into and without providing information about that, we won’t be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should esacpe input when appropriate. If you're going to output the username to an HTML page, use `htmlentities($_COOKIE['username'])`. If you're going to check the username in the database, use `mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username'])` or prepared statements.

And you know users can alter cookies? What happens if I set my `username` cookie to 'Admin' and my `is_logged_in` cookie to 'true'?